# Synonym proposal [webkit-mask] -> [css-mask]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [CSS mask feature](https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/#masking) (which is a recent one) started to gather many questions so I created [css-mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-mask). I just noticed that there is another tag for the same purpose [webkit-mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webkit-mask). The latter one was used for the same feature but when it was an experimental one available on few browsers (mainly webkit ones).

I sugget to make [webkit-mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webkit-mask) (only 12 questions) a synonym of [css-mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-mask) (39 questions and more will come)

The feature is now [supported in many browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-masks) so using the `webkit` prefix will no more be relevant.

Comment: Totally support CSS wearing a mask. I don't want to be infected by that ... this joke goes stale in 2021 (I hope)

Comment: @rene haha! nice one :) .. That would give good ideas for burnination request titles. Unfortunately we still need the *css-mask* even beyond 2021 ;)

Comment: Isn't webkit-mask about either the -webkit-mask-image or -webkit-mask-box-image CSS properties (or maybe both)? Those weren't equivalents of the CSS mask property.

Comment: @RobertLongson the mask-box-image can be linked to mask-border which is also in the same Spec as mask (https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/#propdef-mask-border) .. I think all the mask feature (old and new) can be inlcuded in CSS-mask

Comment: What about the [mask] tag?

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated too ambiguous, we tend to always prefix with css- to avoid any relation with other language. There is already mask/bitmask in C/C++ and it's enough to create a confusion